# Can I return a list of ALL min tuples, using Python's Min function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tuples, iterable

Say I have a list of tuples, like the following:

```
listo = [('a','1'),('b','0'),('c','2'),('d','0')]
```

If I want the lowest tuple, based on the second index of each tuple, I can customize the min function with a `lambda` function, like this:

```
min(listo, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

As it stands, this code would return:

```
In [31]: min(listo, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[31]: ('b', '0')
```

But this only gives me one tuple, and only the first one it encounters at that. What if I wanted ALL the `min` tuples? So it returns something like:

```
In [31]: min(listo, key=lambda x: x[1])
Out[31]: [('b', '0'),('d','0')]
```

Any advice on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by first searching one minimum value and then look for another ones based by the minimum value found.

```
listo = [('a','1'),('b','0'),('c','2'),('d','0')]
minValue = min(listo, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]
minValueList = [x for x in listo if x[1] == minValue]
```

Another approach could be making your own minimum function that uses some kind of list of minimum values but probably it would be much slower for bigger problems.

Comment: Nice, I was kind of doing the second approach already, but was looking for a more "Pythonic" way. I like this, thank you.