# get multiple tuples from list of tuples using min function

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that looks like this

> mylist = [('Part1', 5, 5), ('Part2', 7, 7), ('Part3', 11, 9),
>   ('Part4', 45, 45), ('part5', 5, 5)]

I am looking for all the tuples that has a number closest to my input

now i am using this code

```
result = min([x for x in mylist if x[1] >= 4 and x[2] >= 4])
```

The result i am getting is

> ('part5', 5, 5)

But i am looking for an result looking more like

> [('Part1', 5, 5), ('part5', 5, 5)]

and if there are more tuples in it ( i have 2 in this example but it could be more) then i would like to get all the tuples back

the whole code

```
mylist = [('Part1', 5, 5), ('Part2', 7, 7), ('Part3', 11, 9), ('Part4', 45, 45), ('part5', 5, 5)]
result = min([x for x in mylist if x[1] >= 4 and x[2] >= 4])
print(result)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Firstly, I have to say that in your example the list comprehension does not differ from `mylist` because all numbers are bigger than 4 in your example data. Second: No your code does not return `('part5', 5, 5)` but `('part1', 5, 5)`. Third: I think you misunderstand how the `min` function works on tuples: used this way it simply gives you the tuple with the _smallest first element_, which is `Part1`. You can test it by simply naming it `Part7` or whatever, and the result of `min` will be `('part2', 7, 7)`.

Comment: Besides all that, you should think about how you would like to define the minimum of your list elements. If you can express this idea in a function, you can use this function as a `key` parameter of the `min` function so it will search for the minimum according to _your_ needs.

Comment: HI @SpghttCd Thanks for welcoming
Its a Typo on part 5. anyway if the min function does not give me the result i am after then what should i use?

Comment: As I said, you can use the min function. But its standard sorting algorithm for tuples (order by first elements) seems not to be what you need. So you have to think how you want a list of three-element-tuples to be sorted to be able to name one or more of them "minimal": e.g. is ('partx', 4, 6) to be considered smaller than ('partx', 5, 5)? or equal? is ('partx', 4, 5) equal to ('partx', 5, 4)? ... ...

Comment: Its not about the sorting @SpghttCd i am not getting all the tuples back in the list 
I would like to get all the tuples back that meet the requirements

Using result = min([x for x in mylist if x[1] >= 4 and x[2] >= 4]) already defines that i would like to get back the value closest to my input

So my input is 4 and the closest to that is is 5

If my input would be 10 and 8 then i would only get back  ('Part3', 11, 9) 
Since this is the closest to and higher then

Comment: >= means higher then or equal to that is why i use the AND in the code
these 2 inputs needs to be evaluated and if passed it should print the list it evaluates
there are 2 lists that are evaluated and passed but only 1 printed

Comment: I know, I'm not talking about sorting as the target of an algorithm, but like when you sort, if you want to find the minimum of a list of elements you need some criterion to decide when you have two elements in your hands: which one are you considering "smaller" - i.e. why.

Comment: Everything correct, but after all that filtering according to your Input you apply the python function `min`. And this function needs your definition of how to decide which of two elements is smaller.

Comment: LOL confused. i am expecting that it would evaluate and when passed it should print 

So i get in a list with 5 tuples
first tuple is passed and it should CONTINUE NEXT not abort. and print all the tuples that are passed

Comment: let me break it down. Tuple example
('Part1', 5, 5) <-- if x[1] >= 4 and x[2] >= 4
As the code shows it evaluate element 1 and 2 of the tuple and if its equal to or higer then (AND CLOSEST thats why the MIN function is used) it should pass en resume next tuple. but it seems that the min function aborts as soon as it has a match

Comment: Ok, one step after the other... Your Problem, that `min` returns only the first result and not all minimum values is addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17352387/8300135). In short: calculate the minimum and then get all elements that are equal to that minimum with a simple list comprehension.

Comment: Thanks @SpghttCd I will read that article

Comment: But your mentioned match of the `min` function will not give you more than one result this way either, _because the match was `Part1` - and there is only one single `Part1`, do you understand? `Part1` is the smallest string of all strings in your tuples. That`s why min returns that tuple. It doesn't even look at your numbers x[1] and x[2]_

Comment: Change `Part1` to `Part10` and min will return `('Part2', 7, 7)`. Then additionally change `Part2` to `Part20` and min will return `('Part3', 11, 9)`... ... ...

Comment: That is not true
It does not look at element[0] since i force it to look at [1] and [2]
See screenshot
https://snipboard.io/rKxq8k.jpg

Comment: Why don't you test it with the simple test I told you to do? You force min to _nothing_ else than its standard behaviour. what you do is creating a list comprehension which filters your list, so that the min function is applied to a filtered version of mylist, nothing else.

Comment: Use this key and it will return part 5 instead of part 1

result = min([elem for elem in mylist if elem[1] >= 4 and elem[2] >= 4], key=lambda x: x[1])

Comment: LOL - F... I'm such an idiot, too much of a headache discussion... sorry. Here again the _correct_ test: Change `Part1` to __`Part7`__ and min will return `('Part2', 7, 7)`. Then additionally change `Part2` to __`Part8`__ and min will return `('Part3', 11, 9)`... ... ...

Comment: _(Background: string sorting would of course consider `Part10` still smaller than `Part2`...)_

Comment: To correct that you need to add key=lambda x: x[1] sorry for not including in the start of this thread

Comment: No it does not 
I need to use (>= input) the thread you sent gives me the lowest of the list and not the lowest close to my input

Comment: Right, that's what I said the whole time, you need a Definition of what is smaller, and if in your case it's all only about the middle number, ok, then you have it. And of course my proposed duplicate answeres your question, because it is only the correction of your application of the min function. I did not advise you to leave your filter LC also away.

Comment: Your proposed duplicate? can you repost this please as i did not found any answer in our converation

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17352387/can-i-return-a-list-of-all-min-tuples-using-pythons-min-function?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
threshold = 4
mylist = [('Part1', 5, 5), ('Part2', 7, 7), ('Part3', 11, 9), ('Part4', 45, 45), ('part5', 5, 5)]

filtered = [x for x in mylist if x[1] >= threshold and x[2] >= threshold]
keyfunc = lambda x: x[1]
my_min = keyfunc(min(filtered, key=keyfunc))

result = [v for v in filtered if keyfunc(v)==my_min]


# [('Part1', 5, 5), ('part5', 5, 5)]
```

Comment: who doesn't...? And it's quite fun, as far as I can tell of what I learned so far...

Comment: True 
Its a life time learning
And yes i agree its fun but can be very challenging sometimes

Comment: yep. the biggest challenge in the end often resides right in the middle between our own ears :-)

Comment: xDxD true that will always be the biggest one. Specifically to keep it cool :-)